# Lifecycle hook after view is rerendered when property changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have a component (callout bubble), that needs to calculate it's position based on its native element size. By default it is hidden and thus the element has no size.

When I change hidden binding to false, where do I hook for an event, where I can measure native element's size after it is rendered?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-callout',
  template: `<div #content class="callout-content">
    <div class="callout-header">
      <div class="title">{{title}}</div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100%; flex:1">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>`
})
export class CalloutComponent {
  @HostBinding('hidden')
  @Input()
  isHidden:boolean = false;
  @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>

  ngAfterViewChecked(){
    //called after isHidden is changed, but
    //NOT OK: content.nativeElement.offsetWidth == 0;

    setTimeout(() => {
      // OK: content.nativeElement.offsetWidth == 100;
      // but I would like to get rid of this timer workaround

    }, 100);
  }

  show(){
    this.isHidden = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well you can create the directive which you can attach dynamically to from where the "CalloutComponent" is being called and you can pass the ElementRef / ViewContainer with that and then you can calculate the size of the element.